# I faced to django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

data model is below:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256,default='')
    last_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

I just tried python manage.py migrate.

But, Django tells are...(I don't know what I make mistake.)

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: sessions, data, admin, books, auth, poll, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying data.0003_user_last_time...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1482, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1461, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1317, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1444, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Answer (score 2):

By now you've probably already found out, but `models.DateTimeField` doesn't allow for empty strings. Instead, leave out the default attribute. Django will then set the default of the field to `None`. In addition, set the blank attribute to True as well, so that the field is not required.

```
last_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

See Django Documentation on [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield).